# How to use WM_KEYDOWN properly ?

Tags: c++, winapi, message-queue

I defined a few functions to process Input using WM_KEYDOWN / WM_KEYUP, but only WM_KEYUP seems to work properly. When using the function that utilizes WM_KEYDOWN nothing happens. (Debug message isnt displayed)

When initializing an instance of my Input-class inside my Framework-object, I pass it a pointer to the MSG object that my Framwork uses. (Also the ESCAPE argument inside my function is same as VK_ESCAPE)

Here is my code:
//Input.cpp

```
bool Input::KeyPressed( Keys key )  
{
    if( InputMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN )
    {
        if( InputMsg->wParam == key )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Input::KeyReleased( Keys key )
{
    if( InputMsg->message == WM_KEYUP )
    {
        if( InputMsg->wParam == key )
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

//Framework.cpp

```
bool Framework::Frame()
{
    ProcessInput();
    return true;
}

void Framework::ProcessInput()
{
    if( m_Input->KeyPressed( ESCAPE ) )
    {
        OutputDebugString("Escape was pressed!\n");
    }
}
```

Anyone got an idea why only the KeyReleased() function works but the KeyPressed() doesn't ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When does `Frame()` get called? When/where does `InputMsg` get defined?

Comment: @JonathanPotter `Frame()` gets called inside my `Run()` function which is a while loop: `while( msg.message != WM_QUIT && m_result)
 {
  if( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
  {
   TranslateMessage( &msg );
   DispatchMessage( &msg );
  }
  else
  {
   m_result = Frame();
  }
 }`. When I initialize my Input-object I pass a pointer to a MSG object I created inside my Framework class, so that becomes `InputMsg` (This initialization is done inside the Framework object too). My `while()` loop works with the MSG object from Framwework

Comment: I think we need to see more code. What is your window procedure doing?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have added links to source code down at the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at your code it seems like the problem is the message loop in your `Run()` function:

```
void Framework::Run()
{
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT && m_result)
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            m_result = Frame();
        }
    }
}
```

Look at what this is doing. Every loop iteration, the process is:

- If a message is in the queue, process it
- Otherwise, call the `Frame()` function

When a message is processed it's dispatched to the window and handled by your `WndProc`, which actually does very little. Most of your message processing is done in `Frame()` or the functions called by `Frame()`, but *that function is only called if there **isn't** a message in the queue.*

This explains why you are seeing `WM_KEYUP` but not `WM_KEYDOWN`. The two messages generally come together, at least if you press and release the key at normal speed.

The first time through the loop, `PeekMessage` will retrieve `WM_KEYDOWN` and dispatch it to your window procedure, which does nothing with it.

The loop then repeats, and retrieves `WM_KEYUP`. Again this is sent to the window procedure (which does nothing with it), but with no further messages in the queue the next time around your `Frame()` function is called - which then processes the *most recently retrieved message* but none of the other messages that came before it.

To fix your code you need to refactor your message handling so that every message is processed, not just the last in any particular batch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned a lot once again. For now I solved it by executing my `Frame()` function in both brachnes of the if-statement. As my amount skills and knowledge grows, I will look into implementing more "professional" ways.

Answer (score 0):

WM_KEYDOWN goes through the TranslateMessage block and would reach your block as WM_CHAR.

So I think you must try WM_CHAR instead.

Comment: The window procedure gets `WM_KEYDOWN` as well as `WM_CHAR`. I think we need to see more code...

Comment: [main.cpp](http://www.sourcepod.com/wmhvew16-21374),  [Framework.h](http://www.sourcepod.com/ddapxs18-21375),  [Framework.cpp](http://www.sourcepod.com/jpcplf89-21376),  [Input.h](http://www.sourcepod.com/rmdygr40-21377),  [Input.cpp](http://www.sourcepod.com/rtnuff84-21378)